# How to execute bash terminal commands using php aws-sdk

Tags: laravel, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk, aws-php-sdk

I am using aws-sdk in laravel, and launch an instance successfully using ec2client. After successful launch.

I want to access again ec2 instance through InstanceID and execute some bash/shell/linux commands, not at launch of instance but later whenever i want
is it possible to do it through PHP aws-sdk.

```
$ec2Client = AWS::createClient('ec2');
            $result = $ec2Client->runInstances(array(
                'DryRun' => false,
                'ImageId' => Config::get('aws.ami_id'),
                'MinCount' => 1,
                'MaxCount' => 1,
                'InstanceType' => 't2.micro',
                'SecurityGroupIds' => [
                    'sg-443af4c44806e3e44',
                ],
                'TagSpecifications' => [
                    [
                        'ResourceType' => 'instance',
                        'Tags' => [
                            [
                                'Key' => 'TestFor',
                                'Value' => 'Test 1',
                            ],
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
                'InstanceInitiatedShutdownBehavior' => 'terminate',
                'KeyName' => 'testModule',
                'Monitoring' => [
                    'Enabled' => false,
                ]
            ));
```

Comment: You need to get the IP of the instance (e.g. using $ec2Client->describeInstances...) and then you can connect using the ssh command i.e. `shell_exec("ssh -i /path/to/keyfile 
user@ip \"$commands\"")` where `$commands` can be a string what you need to run

Comment: I found another solution using the Amazon EC2 Simple Systems Manager client. but unfortunately there is no sample code or PHP documentation available for this.
And worst thing is not a single thread I found on google, who uses this PHP SDK before so at least i can get example code from it.